# Testing array elements vs multiple criteria

Tags: ruby

I am trying to create a method `complex_check(n)`, which will do the following:

- Create an array of integers ascending from `0` to `n`
- Check each element of that array against complex criteria.

For example, I have an array from `0..n`, and I want to know which elements of the array are both evenly divisible by 3 and not divisible by 4. I can index through to check for single criteria like `odd?`, etc., but is there a compact way to check each integer against multiple criteria?

Comment: "check each element..." is vague. What do you want the method to return (or to print)? For example, do you want to return an array of the numbers between `0` and `n` that satisfy all the requirements?

Comment: For your information, English sentences start with a capital letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the best I could come up with, I think this is sort of what you're trying to do:

```
def complex_check(n)
  check_array = (0..n).to_a
  check_array.select { |num|
    num % 3 == 0 &&
    num % 4 != 0
  }
end
```

Then using it:

```
complex_check(15)
=> [3, 6, 9, 15]
```

Comment: You can also inline `(0..n)` to avoid creating a variable.

Comment: thanks DivXZero! that's great! simple, concise, easy to read — just what i was looking for!

Comment: jhpratt — would you mind explaining what you mean by 'inlining' my range? I don't see a way to do it without creating a variable but it sounds very interesting.

Answer (score 2):

One of the things Ruby is very good at is processing through lists and other regular data structures. The [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html) extensions common to many things including Array allow you to quickly filter, split, chunk, and otherwise completely rework the data you're dealing with. Often a few quick alterations can do the job.

In this case `select` can be used to filter out undesirable values from your potential candidates in the range 0 to `n`:

```
 def complex_check(n)
   (0..n).select do |v|
      v % 3 == 0 and v % 4 != 0 
   end
 end
```

The key here is using [`select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-select) where any block that returns a logically true value will be a signal to include the element, and otherwise to exclude it. The opposite of this is [`reject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-reject) which works on the same principle, just with inverted logic.

You could also pass these filters in dynamically:

```
def complex_check(n, *tests)
  tests.each_with_object((0..n).to_a) do |test, a|
    a.select!(&test)
  end
end
```

Where your test code ends up looking like this:

```
complex_check(
  50,
  -> (v) { v % 3 == 0 },
  -> (v) { v % 4 != 0 }
)
```

Then you can plug in tests using [lambdas](https://isotope11.com/blog/stabby-lambda) which are little reusable blocks.

Comment: thanks, tadman! i hadn't learned about 'select' yet, very useful!

Answer (score 0):

- create an array of integers ascending from 0 to n

Don't do this if you don't have to, which is almost never.
Use a Range or an Enumerator. They are real easy:

```
0.upto(n).select do |i|  #0.upto(n) results in a Enumerator
  #complex criteria
end

#or

def complex_check(n)
  0.step(n,3).reject{|n| (n%4).zero?}  #0.step(n,3) is an Enumerator
end

p complex_check(15) #= [3, 6, 9, 15]
```